# Мультиязычная страница на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

использую расширение `creocoder/yii2-translateable`, создал модели page и page_lang, сделал все по инструкции, но данные с переводом не приходят. Вот модел page

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use creocoder\translateable\TranslateableBehavior;

class Page extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'translateable' => [
                'class' => TranslateableBehavior::className(),
                'translationAttributes' => ['title', 'body'],
                'translationRelation' => 'pageLangs',
                'translationLanguageAttribute' => 'lang',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function transactions()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => self::OP_INSERT | self::OP_UPDATE,
        ];
    }

    public function getPageLangs()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PageLang::className(), ['page_id' => 'id']);
        //->where(['page_lang' . '.lang' => Yii::$app->language]);
    }

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'page';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['status', 'author_id'], 'integer'],
            [['author_id'], 'required'],
            [['meta_k', 'meta_d', 'slug'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['slug'], 'unique'],
            [['author_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['author_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'meta_k' => 'Meta K',
            'meta_d' => 'Meta D',
            'slug' => 'Slug',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'author_id' => 'Author ID',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
    }
}
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

Забыл в контроллере указать связь `Page::find()->with('pageLangs')->one()`.